# Removing navigated pages from stack in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

I'm using `AppShell` in my .NET MAUI app and here's the scenario:

I have `Page1`, `Page2` and `Page3` defined as my main tab in `AppShell` -- see below:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Home" Icon="home.png">
   <Tab Title="Page 1" Icon="icon1.png">
      <ShellContent Route="Page1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local: Page1}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Page 2" Icon="icon2.png">
      <ShellContent Route="Page2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local: Page2}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Page 3" Icon="icon3.png">
      <ShellContent Route="Page3" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local: Page3}" />
   </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

I tap on tab 3 and go to `Page3`. I then navigate to `Page4` and from there to `Page5` to fill out a form. I navigate to pages 4 and 5 by clicking page elements such as buttons, etc. The routes for `Page4` and `Page5` are defined in `AppShell.xaml.cs` -- see below:

```
...
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Page4), typeof(Page4));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Page5), typeof(Page5));
```

After filling out the form, I want to send the user to `Page2` but also remove `Page4` and `Page5` from the stack.

I tried the following but it's not working exactly right:

```
var route = $"//../../{nameof(Page2)}";
await Shell.Current.GotoAsync(route);
```

This does send the user to `Page2` after I submit the form but doesn't seem to remove `Page4` and `Page5` from the stack. So, if I tap on `Page3` on the tab bar, I still end up on `Page5` instead of `Page3`. That's because originally, I got to `Page5` through this path:

`Page3 => Page4 => Page5`.

How do I make sure I remove `Page4` and `Page5` from the navigation stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem. It seems a new issue for the maui. According to the official document about the  [Backwards navigation in the Maui Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#backwards-navigation),

> `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("../../route");` In this example,
> backwards navigation is performed twice, and then navigation to the
> specified route.

But it didn't work expectedly. So you can post a new issue on the github and use the following code to remove the page in the navigation stack before you navigate.

```
var stack = Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack.ToArray();
for(int i = stack.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
   Shell.Current.Navigation.RemovePage(stack[i]);
}
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Page2");
```

Comment: Yup, manually removing the page from the stack does work but shouldn't be necessary. I did open an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15166 Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering why this wasn't working.

Answer (score 3):

You want the stack to be cleared, and then be on Page2.

According to the doc, this is as simple as:

```cs
await Shell.Current.GotoAsync($"//{nameof(Page2)}");
```

maui shell navigation:

> "//route" ... The matching page will REPLACE the navigation stack.

Comment: Tried that but when I click on tab 3 to go to Page 3, I still end up on Page 5. So the documented approach is not clearing the nav stack.

Comment: Thanks for testing. I’ve added comment to the issue you created.

Comment: I used this and received an error _Global routes currently cannot be the only page on the stack, so absolute routing to global routes is not supported. For now, just navigate to: MyTestPage_.  I needed to include the name of my shell page called `home`.  So either `Shell.Current.GotoAsync($"//home");` to go to the lowest page or `Shell.Current.GotoAsync($"//home/MyTestPage");` to go directly to MyTestPage while removing all other pages in the stack.

Comment: *"received an error"*. Right. That syntax is only permitted for a path that starts with a page in Stack's XAML. (IMHO, Shell is not intuitive.)